# Django: if a value is selected from select box, populate form field

Tags: django

I would like to have a select box (drop down list) `State` that has a few options for example:

```
VIC
NSW
SA
...
```

and then in my forms.py I have a field for example `City` (which is a site name), for example:

```
Melbourne
Sydney
```

I am pretty new to Django so please keep that in mind, sorry.

I am not working on a crucial project or anything at this stage, just trying to learn Django, so if I need to create a new project, no biggie.

I am guessing some sort of javascript or something may be required to update the `City` form field dynamically?

Thanks in advance.

edit:
I meant like a test project sorry should have been clearer, here's what I have at the moment:

So for example, if I select NSW, Sydney, then the Address = 10 Sydney Road (so I would like the field `Address` = `"10 Sydney Road"`

`forms.py:`

```
STATE_CHOICES = (
('NSW', 'VIC', '...'),
)
CITY_CHOICES = (
('Sydney', 'Melbourne', '...'),
)
```

`models.py:`

```
state = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
city = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=CITY_CHOICES)
address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

`views.py:`

```
@login_required
def configs_edit(request, pk):
    configs = get_object_or_404(Configurations, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ConfigsForm(request.POST, instance=configs)
        if form.is_valid():
            configs = form.save(commit=False)
            configs.author = request.user
            configs.save()
            return redirect('configs_detail', pk=configs.pk)
    else:
        form = ConfigsForm(instance=configs)
    return render(request, 'blah/configs_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

`urls.py:`

```
url(r'^configs/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$', views.configs_edit, name='configs_edit'),
```

`template:`

```
{% extends "blah/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>New Configuration</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}   
      <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You will definitely need to create a project. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this myself:

I manually populated the form with:

`template:`

```
<div>
  STATE: {{ form.state }}
</div>
<div>
  CITY: {{ form.city }}
</div>
<div>
  ADDRESS: {{ form.Address }}
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#id_state').change(function() {
      var selected = $(this).val();
      if(selected == 'VIC') {
        $('#id_Address').val('10 Melbourne Street');
# - to fill in more than one field:  $('#id_blah').val('other val');
      }
      else if(selected == 'WA') {
        $('#id_Address').val('10 West Australia Street');
      }
      else if(selected == 'SA') {
        $('#id_Address').val('10 South Australia Street');
      }
      else if(selected == 'NSW') {
        $('#id_Address').val('Sydney');
      }
      else if(selected == 'QLD') {
        $('#id_Address').val('10 Queensland Street');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

`choices.py:`

```
STATE_CHOICES = (
    ('NSW', ("NSW")),
    ('VIC', ("VIC")),
    ('SA', ("SA")),
    ('WA', ("WA")),
    ('QLD', ("QLD"))
)
CITY_CHOICES = (
    ('Sydney', ("Sydney")),
    ('Melbourne', ("Melbourne"))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use JavaScript, please refer to the `onchange` event. Rembember it is still necessary to perform validation on the server side.